# 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Complete throught a reference with static type Class

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i'm doing a flash web site and i want to import a html file to the flash file

this is the code which i found on the Ehow
[here is the tutorail](http://www.ehow.com/how_8310976_import-html-text-flash.html)

```
var displayText:TextField = new TextField();

displayText.scaleY = stage.stageHeight/600;
displayText.scaleX = stage.stageWidth/1225;
displayText.width = 400;
displayText.height = 700;

var importFile:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var requestedFile: URLRequest = new URLRequest("HTML/الدرس الأول.htm");

importFile.load(requestedFile);

importFile.addEventListener(Event.Complete, htmlloaded_fn);

function htmlloaded_fn(event: Event): void {

    displayText.htmlText = importFile.data;

}

addChild(displayText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event property COMPLETE should be in uppercase:

```
importFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, htmlloaded_fn);
```

By convention all static properties of a class are written in uppercase with underscores between words.

Comment: do u know how can i change the color of the text cuz there is nothing showing ?!

Comment: You use a TextFormat object, and apply it to your TextField before you set the text. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html  Please ask a new question if you need help getting it working.